# unrecognized selector sent to instance on deviceOrientationDidChange

Tags: objective-c, portrait, device-orientation, unrecognized-selector

Right now my app should only supports Portrait. On Summary/Supported Device Orientations I have only selected Portrait so I'm hoping that my app will not rotate. I was testing the app on a device and suddenly I'm getting the following error randomly:

```
[UIButtonContent deviceOrientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It happens when I rotate the device SOMETIMES, is not consistent, and is not always over UIBUttonContent. I supposed that if I only select Portrait, deviceOrientationDidChange should not be called or should be ignored.

Other times my app crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=something) but it happens when I rotate the device so I'm guessing that both errors are related.

I don't know what to do with this, it's hard to debug because I don't have feedback, the All Exceptions Breakpoint is not being called, so I don't know where and exactly why this is happening. Any idea on how to debug this is welcome.

Comment: Could do with some more code...

Comment: I know, but it happens across all the app, so I really don't know wich code to put here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue a long time ago, but I think is good to share what actually helped me on this case.

After trying everything with no results with Instruments I started debugging old-school. I had an idea of "where" the error was so I just commented all the code on that section. I was right, the bug just disappeared along with some functionalities. After that I made "binary uncommenting" (uncomment one half) till I got the bug line. It was a third party library, I had an object that was not being released properly.

Answer (score 1):

These are the classic signs of a memory management error.  You have over-released some object and it has been deallocated while something else still references it.  Later, something messages it. In some cases a new object has taken its place, but that object doesn't understand the messages it's receiving.  In other cases, there's no valid object and you get a crash.

Edited to second the advice to use the Zombies instrument to find the over-release.

Comment: This is weird because I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class that should be called with `deviceOrientationDidChange:`? When this happens, it usually means that you have a dangling reference to a deallocated object. You should try profiling your app with Instruments in "Zombies" mode.

Comment: I just updated to xcode 4.3.2 and Instruments disappeared, fixing that first.

Comment: I usually just do Product => Profile from XCode.

Comment: is there a way to use zombies on the device? I don`t see the option

Comment: No, because zombie detection works by not reallocating used memory, it is not available on the device. But you can still rotate simulator by doing Command + arrow keys.